# Preload a popup with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, magnific-popup

so I have a the following code:

```
<section id="modal" class="generique">
   <div id="iFrame">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//videopub.php" defer="" async=""></script>
   </div>
</section>
```

In this popup I have a script use to show publicity. The problem is that my script is not loaded when I look in source page and in firebuug console.
Probably I need to make a preload or what is the solution for this case? If I put this script in header that is loaded, but if I put in popup the script is not loaded.

Comment: Why do you want it to be in the HTML straight away? Depending on what you're trying to achieve, there may be better solutions than preloading.

Comment: will be a video publicity

Comment: What is the content of videopub.php? Also when you say 'not loaded' do you mean a 404 or empty?

Comment: This <script> does not appear in the source of page

Answer (score -1):

Why not using this jquery plugin 'fancybox' : http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples

Otherwise we need your JS code to be able to help.